# How to tan in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How are you supposed to tan in new leaf? I want my character to have a tan but i don't know how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Tan)

During the summer, (the second half of July–September) it is possible to get a tan, as real humans would. In order to do this, the player must stand in the sun long enough (note that there must be a clear sky outside and it must be during daytime), the player's skin will go up through levels. There are five different levels, each one having a darker hue than the other. Unlike the older games, City Folk and Wild World, you start to notice the tan right away, but you can only achieve 1 level per day.

The player can also get a tan anytime in the year, as long as they visit Tortimer Island in the morning. The only thing that stops a tan from appearing is an umbrella.

Answer (score 8):

> During the summer, (the second half of July–September) it is possible to get a tan, as real humans would. In order to do this, the player must stand in the sun long enough (note that there must be a clear sky outside and it must be during daytime), the player's skin will go up through levels. There are five different levels, each one having a darker hue than the other. Unlike the older games, City Folk and Wild World, you start to notice the tan right away, but you can only achieve 1 level per day.

[image]

[Source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Tan)

Answer (score 0):

According to [nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Tan),

> During summer (the second half of July to September) it is possible to get a tan. By standing in the sun long enough (note that there must be a clear sky outside and it must be during daytime), the player's skin will go up through levels. They must stand out there for 15+ min. The best time for tanning is 3:00 PM. There are 5 different levels, each one having a darker tan than the other. The tan, however, will appear the following day.

[image: TannedPlayer]

Answer (score 0):

> Like real life, getting a tan is not quick, although it does happen faster in the game than in real life.
>
> To get a tan, you need to be outside on a warm, sunny day. Tans are easier to get in the summer. There cannot be clouds. You can do this in your town, but going to Tortimer Island guarantees the correct conditions for getting a tan. You can run around fishing, planting, and swimming if you like, or you can leave the game on and the 3DS open (not in sleep mode). It will take a few hours of being in the sun for a tan to appear. It may take multiple days to get to the darkest color. The tan will NOT appear until the next day.

[Source](http://www.supercheats.com/3ds/questions/animal-crossing-new-leaf/317228/What-is-the-quickest-way-to-ge.htm)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130705095019AAq3UGV)

> July 16 to September 15 - Tanning Season
>
> Your player can tan while playing outside at least 15 minutes between
>   10am and  5pm, if it is not raining (and your player is not carrying
>   an umbrella or  wearing an item that prevents tanning).